# IAS vs ground speed when calculating speed to fly in wind

Tags: glider, glide-ratio

It's common for discussions around a glider's Polar Curve to describe how to use the Polar Curve to identify the best speed (Indicated Airspeed, IAS) to fly in a given wind condition (let's assume a straight headwind for this discussion). You do this by calculating the tangent to the curve from the point (wind speed, 0) on the graph, and the IAS where the tangent meets the curve is the IAS that will give you the best glide slope for that wind condition.

However, wind is reported relative to ground speed, but IAS is definitely not equivalent to ground speed at higher altitudes. **Why is it OK to "subtract" windspeed from IAS on the polar when they aren't comparable really?** Is the error just so small that it doesn't matter in practice? If you wanted a mathematically accurate calculation would you first have to convert wind speed to IAS or vice versa (probably by using the 2% per 1000 ft estimate)?

Comment: Would you put a picture of the chart in your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 100% correct to suggest that if we are working with a polar curve that has units of IAS, the wind speed needs to be converted to similar units before we can properly find the best speed to fly for best glide angle over the ground by means of the tangent line method.

Or conversely we could convert the IAS to TAS, and use the true wind speed.

Usually it doesn't matter much, but sometimes it might.  Especially at high actual altitudes or density altitudes.

You clearly have the understanding sufficient to work out for yourself how much the difference would be in various real-world situations.